# Lighttpd rewrite local

Tags: android, wordpress, .htaccess, lighttpd

I'm running `lighttpd` locally on my Android tablet, and am working on a Wordpress site. It's working perfectly, except for the URL rewrite.

Urls only work as:

`localhost:8080/fb/index.php/hello-world` instead of `localhost:8080/fb/hello-world`

This is a pretty common issue and there is a lot of info out there on it, but I haven't been able to get any of it to work. I'm assuming I'm leaving something simple out.

Currently `lighttpd.conf` looks like below. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix it? I would be eternally grateful :)

```
server.document-root = "/mnt/sdcard/www"
dir-listing.activate = "enable"
server.errorlog = "/mnt/sdcard/wwwconf/server.log"

server.tag = "lighttpd/1.4.29 for Android - BitWebServer"

server.port = 8080

index-file.names = ("index.php", "index.html", "index.htm", "home.php","home.html","home.htm")

fastcgi.server = (
  ".php" =>
        (( "host" => "127.0.0.1",
           "port" => 9003,
        ))
)
alias.url = ("/phpmyadmin" => "/data/data/com.andi.serverweb/files/phpmyadmin")

server.max-request-size = 1000000
server.network-backend = "writev"
server.upload-dirs =( "/data/data/com.andi.serverweb/files/lighttpd/tmp" )

mimetype.use-xattr  = "disable"

mimetype.assign             = (
  ".appcache"     =>    "text/cache-manifest",  
  ".pdf"          =>    "application/pdf",
  ".sig"          =>    "application/pgp-signature",
  ".spl"          =>    "application/futuresplash",
  ".class"        =>    "application/octet-stream",
  ".ps"           =>    "application/postscript",
  ".torrent"      =>    "application/x-bittorrent",
  ".dvi"          =>    "application/x-dvi",
  ".gz"           =>    "application/x-gzip",
  ".pac"          =>    "application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig",
  ".swf"          =>    "application/x-shockwave-flash",
  ".tar.gz"       =>    "application/x-tgz",
  ".tgz"          =>    "application/x-tgz",
  ".tar"          =>    "application/x-tar",
  ".zip"          =>    "application/zip",
  ".mp3"          =>    "audio/mpeg",
  ".m3u"          =>    "audio/x-mpegurl",
  ".wma"          =>    "audio/x-ms-wma",
  ".wax"          =>    "audio/x-ms-wax",
  ".ogg"          =>    "application/ogg",
  ".wav"          =>    "audio/x-wav",
  ".gif"          =>    "image/gif",
  ".jpg"          =>    "image/jpeg",
  ".jpeg"         =>    "image/jpeg",
  ".png"          =>    "image/png",
  ".xbm"          =>    "image/x-xbitmap",
  ".xpm"          =>    "image/x-xpixmap",
  ".xwd"          =>    "image/x-xwindowdump",
  ".css"          =>    "text/css",
  ".html"         =>    "text/html",
  ".htm"          =>    "text/html",
  ".js"           =>    "text/javascript",
  ".asc"          =>    "text/plain",
  ".c"            =>    "text/plain",
  ".cpp"          =>    "text/plain",
  ".log"          =>    "text/plain",
  ".conf"         =>    "text/plain",
  ".text"         =>    "text/plain",
  ".txt"          =>    "text/plain",
  ".spec"         =>    "text/plain",
  ".dtd"          =>    "text/xml",
  ".xml"          =>    "text/xml",
  ".mpeg"         =>    "video/mpeg",
  ".mpg"          =>    "video/mpeg",
  ".mov"          =>    "video/quicktime",
  ".qt"           =>    "video/quicktime",
  ".avi"          =>    "video/x-msvideo",
  ".asf"          =>    "video/x-ms-asf",
  ".asx"          =>    "video/x-ms-asf",
  ".wmv"          =>    "video/x-ms-wmv",
  ".bz2"          =>    "application/x-bzip",
  ".tbz"          =>    "application/x-bzip-compressed-tar",
  ".tar.bz2"      =>    "application/x-bzip-compressed-tar",
  ".odt"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
  ".ods"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
  ".odp"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
  ".odg"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics",
  ".odc"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart",
  ".odf"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula",
  ".odi"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image",
  ".odm"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master",
  ".ott"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template",
  ".ots"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template",
  ".otp"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template",
  ".otg"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template",
  ".otc"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template",
  ".otf"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template",
  ".oti"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image-template",
  ".oth"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web",
  ""              =>    "application/octet-stream"
)

server.modules   = ( 
"mod_rewrite",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_access",
    "mod_auth",
    "mod_status",
    "mod_simple_vhost",
    "mod_evhost",
    "mod_userdir",
    "mod_secdownload",
    "mod_fastcgi",
    "mod_proxy",
    "mod_cgi",
    "mod_ssi",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_usertrack",
    "mod_expire",
    "mod_rrdtool",
    "mod_accesslog" 
)
$HTTP["host"] =~ "localhost:8080/fb/" {
  url.rewrite-final = (

    # Exclude some directories from rewriting
    "^/(wp-admin|wp-includes|wp-content|gallery2)/(.*)" => "$0",

    # Exclude .php files at root from rewriting
    "^/(.*.php)" => "$0",

    # Handle permalinks and feeds
    "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php/$1"
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your conditional on the `$HTTP["host"]`. Host is just that, host. In your case it would be `localhost`. To accomplish checking host, port, and url, you'd need the do the following:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "localhost" {
    $SERVER["port"] == "8080" {
        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/fb/.*" {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Those are absolute checks on `host == localhost` and `port == 8080` and a regex on `url` checking that it starts with `/fb/`.